# Vuetify 3 v-dialog not opened immediately after click on mobile browser

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I am using vue3 and vuetify3 to build a site. When I click the button to open v-dialog, it won't be shown immediately. And during this delay time, whole site will be freezed until the dialog is opened.(Closing dialog has same issue) When there are more objects in the page, it will take more time to open and close.
In addition, I found that there just a liitle bit delay on desktop device but huge delay on mobile device.
How could I imporve the performance of this?

---

**Environment**
Vue: 3.2.37
Vuetify: 3.0.0-beta5
Mobile Device: iPhone 13 Pro Max (iOS 15.5)
Mobile Browser: Safari, Edge, Chrome
Desktop OS: Windows 11
Desktop Browser: Edge, Chrome

---

This is my code structure

**ItemList.vue**

```
<template>
 <div v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="index">
  <Item :item="item" />
 </div>

 <v-dialog v-model="dialog.open" transition="fade-transition">
   <!-- item detail -->
   <div>{{ dialog.item }}</div>
   <v-btn @click="dialog.open = false">Close</v-btn>
 </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import Item from './Item.vue';
export default {
  name: 'ItemList',
  data: () => ({
    dialog: {
      open: false,
      item: {}
    },
  }),
  props: ['itemList'],
  components: {
    Item,
  },
  methods: {  
    openDialog(item) {
      this.dialog.item = item;
      this.dialog.open = true;
    },   
  }
};
</script>
```

**Item.vue**

```
<template>
 <div>
  <!-- item text and image -->
  <v-btn @click.stop="openDialog(item)">Info</v-btn>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Item',
  data: () => ({}),
  components: {},
  props: ['item'],
  methods: { 
    openDialog(item) {
      this.$emit('openDialog', item);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: vuetify next is horribly inconsistent release to release, guess why it's `beta` (that's a compliment to the vuetify team to be honest, I'd say vuetify next is pre-alpha at best) - however, I thought they'd fixed all the absolute garbage that is `v-dialog`